# How can I represent the vectors below as box plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, boxplot

I have below these three vectors:

```
CoverageArea_mean = [84.4735,0,21.1779,4.5211,6.4247,2.3795,2.1416,0]; %FEC = 3.8x10^-3
CoverageArea_min = [98.5128,92.5640,21.1779,21.1779,6.9007,6.9007,2.1416,2.1416]; %FEC = 3.8x10^-3
CoverageArea_max = [70.1963,0,19.0363,0.4759,5.9488,0.2380,2.1416,0]; %FEC = 3.8x10^-3
```

I would like to draw them as in the figure below:
[image]

```
x = [15 15 30 30 45 45 60 60];
```

I am not sure If they will be fit for the box plot or not. I want to take a value from the three vectors every time and represent them as a above.

Any idea or assistance, please?

Comment: do you want the T size proportional to the value on top (or bottom)? or should all T have same size, like in the picture in question?

Comment: @JohnBG Thank you, sir, for your comment. For every shape, I need it to represent the min, max and mean values. It is ok the T has not the same size. I just need to represent the values.

Comment: @JohnBG I modified the post a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** I call **marker** (as in oscilloscopes) what in MATLAB is called **pointer**.

**2.-** I have modified Davidson's function `plot_candlesticks` available here

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9893-candlesticks?s_tid=srchtitle_financial%20charts_23

Mathworks File exchange name: **candlesticks** version 1.0.0.0 (1.44 KB) by Bill Davidson

Bill grants permission for modifications.

**3.-** With the following functions and test script you can generate graphs like this

[image]

The addition of text labels is a really easy task that I have started, as you can see in the test script, but ran out of time for this question so I let you finish it off, let me know if you encounter any problem.

I recommend you use command `text`  outside the supplied functions, after plotting the graph

**4.-** I give you 2 functions: `plot_tees` and `plot_bars` . The function you asked for is `plot_tees`

```
function [hpt]=plot_tees(ax1,x,highs,lows,opens,closes,sh,col_stick)
% plot_tees plots T and inverted T on supplied data points

% input checks: PENDING
% make sure x has no gaps and same interval
% make sure all input lengths are the same : x highs lows opens closes
% check amount inputs and expected formats ok

    middle=sh.middle
    hwbody=sh.hwbody
    hwshad=sh.hwshad
    xbody=sh.xbody
    xshad=sh.xshad
    
    npoints=length(highs);

    hpt=[0 0 0];
    for k1=1:npoints
        hp1(k1,1)=plot(ax1,[.5+x(k1)-.2 .5+x(k1)+.2],[highs(k1) highs(k1)],'Color',col_stick,'LineWidth',1.1);  % top --
        hp1(k1,2)=plot(ax1,[.5+x(k1)-.2 .5+x(k1)+.2],[lows(k1) lows(k1)],'Color',col_stick,'LineWidth',1.1);  % low --
        hp1(k1,3)=plot(ax1,[.5+x(k1) .5+x(k1)],[lows(k1) highs(k1)],'Color',col_stick,'LineWidth',1.1);  % the actual stick

        hpt=[hpt; hp1];

    end
    hpt(1,:)=[];

end
```

and `plot_bars`

```
function [hpt]=plot_bars(ax1,x,highs,lows,opens,closes,col_down,sh,col_up)
% plot_bar plots high-low bars on supplied data

% input checks
% make sure x has no gaps and same interval
% make sure all lengths are the same :x highs lows opens closes


middle=sh.middle
hwbody=sh.hwbody
hwshad=sh.hwshad
xbody=sh.xbody
xshad=sh.xshad

npoints=length(x);

colors=closes<opens;
colors=char(colors*col_down+(1-colors)*col_up); % 'k' black 'w' white 'r' red 'b' blue or custom RGB [r g b] range [0 1]

% h1=figure(1)

hpt=[];
for k1=1:npoints
     hp1=patch(ax1,x(k1)+xbody,[opens(k1),opens(k1),closes(k1),closes(k1),opens(k1)],colors(k1));
    hpt=[hpt hp1];
end

end
```

This is the **TEST SCRIPT HERE :**

```
close all;clear all;clc

% opns : opens  clos : closes , avoiding var names too close to reserved names

col_down='r'
col_up='r'
col_stick='k'

% this is to avoid having to make changes inside each function
sh.middle=0.5;
sh.hwbody=sh.middle/2;
sh.hwshad=sh.hwbody/10;
sh.xbody=sh.middle+[-sh.hwbody sh.hwbody sh.hwbody -sh.hwbody -sh.hwbody];
sh.xshad=sh.middle+[-sh.hwshad sh.hwshad sh.hwshad -sh.hwshad -sh.hwshad];

% time reference
npoints=15  % amount CONSECUTIVE days
x=[1:npoints]  % day points

% data
y_mean0=50   % DC to avoid graph 002
y=rand(npoints,1)-0.5
opns=y_mean0+cumsum(y)  
highs=opns+rand(npoints,1)
lows=opns-rand(npoints,1)
clos=opns+(highs-lows).*(rand(npoints,1)-0.5)

% plot frame
h1=figure(1)
ax1=gca
plot(ax1,[x(1)-1 x(end)+1],[y_mean0 y_mean0])
hold(ax1,'on')
plot(ax1,x,zeros(1,numel(x))+y_mean0,'|','Color',[.7 .7 .7])   % days reference

% plot data spans
hp1=plot_tees(ax1,x,highs,lows,opns,clos,sh,col_stick);
hold on
grid on;   % off | minor
hp2=plot_bars(ax1,x,highs,lows,opns,clos,col_down,sh,col_up);

% include text tags
prec=7   % precision : amount total digits into string '.' not a digit
str_highs=num2str(highs,prec);
str_lows=num2str(lows,prec);
tr1=2 % trim, in case needed : how many decimal digits to drop from right hand side
str_highs(:,[end-tr1+1:end])=[];
str_lows(:,[end-tr1+1:end])=[];

% PENDING

% figure properties
h1.Name='graph 01';
h1.NumberTitle='off';
h1.ToolBar='auto';  % none | figure
h1.MenuBar='figure';  % | figure
h1.Color=[.7 .7 .7];  % figure background colour
ax1.Color=[.9 .9 .9]

% T-marker properties :  modify T-marker properties here
for k1=1:1:size(hp1,1)
    for k2=1:1:size(hp1,2)
    
        hp1(k1,k2).LineWidth=1.1;
        hp1(k1,k2).Color=[.9 .5 .3];
    
    end
end

% bars properties : modify bar properties here
for k1=1:1:size(hp2,2)
    
    hp2(k1).EdgeColor='none';
    
end

% plot aditional graphs
plot(ax1,x+.5,opns,'c','LineWidth',1.5)
```

**5.-** I am **not using the data you supplied** in the question. Instead I use randomly generated points.

You should have no trouble in replacing the random data with your data.

Let me know if any handicap.

**5.1.-** The **time reference** you supplied doesn't seem to match the supplied values; `x` has doubled values and there are more values than days

**5.2.-** The **mean value** hardly ever is exactly the average between each high and each low

**5.3.-** Using the data I know I could show how to do things like **changing properties** and including **additional graphs**, because with a clear time reference is available.

**6.-** Because you may need to change colours, bars opacity, bars edge, bars presence, and thickness of any, as well as there may be need to turn on/off each text field on graph (of each point and of all points) **all handles to properties are now available**.

**Additional Comments :**

**7.-** MATLAB built-in colours handy here

[image]

And some other commonly used custom colours

[image]

Any colour is available, just specify the RGB as vector `[1 1 1]` range of each element `[0 1]` 0: black, 1: white.

**8.-** **MATLAB built-in markers** are : `arrow` (default) `ibeam` `crosshair` `watch` `topl` `botr` `circle` `cross` `fleur` `left` `right` `top` `bottom` and `hand`.

One can also create **custom pointers** setting up figure property `PointerShapeCData`.

But none of these pointers are useful here because they are all **16x16 only**, size matters.

This is why I asked in first place if the Ts had to be same size, or more reasonably, like in financial/investment/banking graphs you asked for T-markers proportional to the specified span, for each point.

**9.-** This question-answer has nothing to do with what is commonly known as T-graphs : 2 lists side by side to compare features.

**10.-** use `uifigure` instead of figure if you are building your app with App Builder.